# How to extract formatted max date value from MySQL table

Tags: sql, string, date, max, date-format

In my database value of field date is saved in format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` in `varchar`

Suppose my db contains date `21/09/2012 01:01:01` and `02/10/2012 03:04:08`

I want to findout maximum date so I am converting string to date by the following query

`SELECT max(str_to_date(dt.date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) as max_date from employee emp where emp_id=1;`

and this returning the results correct but in this format: `2012-10-02 03:04:08`

But I want the result in this format: `02/10/2012 03:04:08`. So I have used following query but it returns the result:

`SELECT max(date_format(str_to_date(emp.date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) as max_date from employee emp where emp_id=1;`

RESULT: `21/09/2012 01:01:01`

Answer (score 4):

This seems far too simple to be right, but have you tried switching the order in which you're calling the functions?

Instead of `SELECT max(date_format(str_to_date(emp.date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s'),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')) as max_date from employee emp where emp_id=1;`

Try `SELECT date_format(max(str_to_date(emp.date,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as max_date from employee emp where emp_id=1;`

Answer (score 3):

The conversion of the date to a string shouldn't be necessary for the max() function to work correctly. You should be able to run the following query and get the result you need:

```
SELECT date_format(max(emp.date), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') FROM employee emp WHERE emp_id=1
```